# Prevent passing rvalue by reference

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, pass-by-reference

In my project the majority of objects are created in an arena, and it is guaranteed that they are exist during a user session.
So it is quite safe for some class to have const reference as a member field, for example:

```
class A {
 public:
  A(const string& str) : str_(str) {}

 private:
  const string& str_;
};
```

But here there is a pitfall. By mistake it is possible to create an instance of `A` the following way:

```
A a("some temporal string object");
```

In that line the temporal `string` object has been implicitly created and destroyed. So after that `a` stores incorrect reference.

How to prevent that behavior? It would be better if it results in compile error...

Comment: If your arena just distributes a big block of memory it shouldn't be difficult to check if `this` belongs to it and add a relevant `assert` in the constructor. An alternative could be to make the constructor private and provide just a factory method that uses the arena to allocate the object. This has also the advantage that mistakes are detected at compile time.

Comment: No wait, I realize now that you want that to work for arbitrary types, so the second approach isn't feasible.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, yep, types shouldn't know anything about arena ) And I wrote about the arena is only to justify references as a member fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to have an overload which matches better to rvalues, so that the compiler takes that one over the `const&` one.

So, a temporary better matches a `&&` than a `const&`, so you just need to provide such a constructor and `delete` it:

```
class A {
 public:
  A(const string& str) : str_(str) {}
  A(string&&) = delete; // this constructor is a better match for rvalues

 private:
  const string& str_;
};
```

Comment: Still, this doesn't help with stack-allocated objects.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Right, but then the only viable solution is just to not take by reference at all IMO.

Comment: Yep, probably the right solution would be just to take some smart-pointer-like object that wraps a pointer and that can only be generated by the arena.

Comment: @MatteoItalia wrapping a `std:: reference_wrapper<T>` in some `arena_allocated<T>` struct is exactly what I was thinking of for an answer. Don't have the time to write one now, though.